# How do I install the elementary OS 5.0 theme to flatpak?

Tags: release-juno, themes

Applications installed via flatpak use the default bundled theme and it cannot access the system-installed themes. As a workaround, they allow extensions(?) is what I think they're called so I can import themes into it and make the apps use that instead. But I don't know how to get the elementary OS 5.0 theme into that.